Problem connecting two laptops with serial connection
using the following python code to create a serial connection to another pc, when the connection opens, the other pc stops working until i close the connection then it returns working properly and executes the commands done while the connection is open (like moving the mouse and writing the keyboard inputs).
import serial 
import time

Baudrate = 9600
Port = 'COM5'

ZSerial = serial.Serial(port=Port, baudrate=Baudrate)
ZSerial.timeout = 2
ZSerial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ZSerial.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ZSerial.xonxoff = False
ZSerial.rtscts = False
ZSerial.dsrdtr = False

print (ZSerial.is_open)

if ZSerial.is_open:
    while True:
        size = ZSerial.inWaiting()
        if size:
            data = ZSerial.read(size)
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print ('z1serial not open')

I made sure that configuration is ok, also an application called 'COM port analyzer' can read the data, but unfortunately my python app has that problem.
any help please?

It seems that the text written in the question is unclear as to what the problem is. The program presented does not do anything with the data read from the serial port, it is just thrown away. You will need to clarify what you want to do with this communication program, what functions you want it to have, and then implement it.

I just need to read the data sent by the other pc using serial port, the problem is when the code opens the serial connection with the other pc, the other pc stops working.

In that case, the problem is not the program presented in the question, but what kind of program is running on the other PC of the connection partner, and whether there is any configuration or setting that affects such a stoppage. Please add information about other PC.
